# Magnific Popup does not make gray backround on screen

Tags: jquery, popup

I have this page to open youtube video popup:

http://daf-daf.co.il/test/youtube.html

when clicking, the background does not become gray like the example page:

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

(in Open Yputube Video)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Popup background trying to fill entire page, but your page has small height, so it doesn't show up properly